# Relative Compactness $\Rightarrow$ Compactness

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I try to figure out: $(\overline{A}^U\text{ compact in }U )\Rightarrow( \overline{A}^X\text{ compact in }X)$ ...while $U\in\mathcal{T}$

It's clear for the case: $\overline{A}^X\subseteq U$

But else, this must be because adding a boundary makes the situation just better. I simply don't know how to prove this idea...

...ok the missing fact was: $(X\text{ Hausdorff})$
*Problem solved!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\text{ relatively precompact}\Rightarrow \overline{A}^U\text{ relatively compact}\Rightarrow\overline{A}^U\text{ compact}\Rightarrow\overline{A}^U\text{ closed}\Rightarrow\overline{A}^X=\overline{A}^U\text{ compact}$